# How to write this function used in finding a series of elements in an array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, variadic-templates

How to write this function used in finding a series of elements in an array?

I’ve written a function named find that is used in finding an element whether is in an array or not. Now I want to used find() to find a series of elements, if all elements is exist in this array then the function will return true or return false :

```
template <typename T>
template <typename ...Args>
bool Vector<T>::find(const Args &...args) const {
    std::deque<bool> findDeque;
    findDeque.push_back(this->find(args...));        //The statement will lead to Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x...)
    auto begin {findDeque.cbegin()};
    auto end {findDeque.cend()};
    if(begin == end) {
        return false;
    }
    while(begin != end) {
        if(!*begin++) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried :

```
findDeque.push_back(this->find(args)...);
```

and

```
...
bool Vector<T>::find(Args &&...args) const {
...
findDeque.push_back(this->find(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
...
```

Maybe I study the parameter packet expand badly.
How should I revise the function to make it find successfully.

Comment: I feel like it would be clearer to do this with recursion. Right now you find all elements when you could technically stop when one of them isnt found. Using recursion and stopping if one is not found (or you ran out of elements) is what I would do.

Comment: Also, do you really need `template <typename ...Args>`? I would assume you can only find other objects of type `T` in a `Vector` of `T`

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks bro. For a variadic template function, it is mentioned in C++ Primer that it is usually a recursion, but I forgot... Now I solved it. As for template<typename ...Args>, you are right, but I tried const T &... and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite recursion because you never peel off one argument when you call `find()` from itself.  The recursion never gets any closer to terminating, and eventually...stack overflow!